# How to obtain an absolute path from directory_iterator in Visual Studio 2012 <filesystem>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, filesystems

I'm trying to obtain an absolute path from `directory_iterator` in Visual Studio 2012 . It was possible in earlier versions of Boost library with `native_file_string()`. None of the function members available now returns absolute path. I ended up having to combine directory path with file name:

```
string         filePath = "C:\\Eigen\\CMakeLists.txt";
string         prefix   = path (filePath).parent_path().string() + "/";
vector<string> fullPaths;  // Full paths of all files in directory.

for (auto i = directory_iterator (path (filePath).branch_path()); i != directory_iterator(); ++i) 
    fullPaths.push_back (prefix + i->path().string());
```

Is there a way to have a directory iterator capable of returning the full path? In above loop, I tried:

```
auto s1 = i->path().branch_path();
auto s2 = i->path().directory_string();
auto s4 = i->path().file_string();
auto s5 = i->path().root_path();
auto s6 = i->path().parent_path();
auto s7 = i->path().string();
auto s8 = i->path().basename();
auto s9 = i->path().filename();
auto sa = i->path().root_name();
auto sb = i->path().relative_path();
```

and none of them returns full path.

**EDIT:** I noticed that using `recursive_directory_iterator` instead of `directory_iterator` will produce full (absolute) path. Is this by design? What if I don't want recursive iteration?

Answer (score 3):

Your are probably looking for [`absolute()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#absolute), which is a non-member function.

Comment: I seems Microsoft didn't implement it yet.

Comment: @PaulJurczak According to [this](http://cpprocks.com/introduction-to-tr2-filesystem-library-in-vs2012/) the version in VS2012 is based on Boost.Filesystem v2. You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx) its documentation. I think the function equivalent to `absolute` is [`complete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874892.aspx) but I'm not sure.

Comment: @llonesmiz: Oooops, I should have tested it better. `complete` is a concatenation of initial path and file name, so it's not it.